# changing mysql --log-error to --syslog

Tags: debian, mysql, sysvinit

I am using here MySQL 5.7.19 from Oracle in Debian Jessie and Stretch.

```
ps ax | grep mysql
/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --log-error=syslog.srv.rede.err --pid-file
```

I would like to take out the --log-error parameter from it, and replace it with --syslog.

Somewhat when reading the associate boot scripts I got the (wrong?) idea the parameters were being built from the configuration files, and I replaced in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf  the line

```
log-error      = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

for

```
syslog
```

I restarted the mysql service, and it did not work as expected.

How can I configure logging to syslog in a "Debian way"?

EDIT: I opened the question in the spirit of finding it out about alternative ways besides editing init scripts

Comment: This would be the "Oracle way" as you cannot be using a Debian-packaged MySQL.  The latest available Debian-packaged version as I write this is 5.7.18, and one has to go to "testing" for that.  Debian 8 has MySQL 5.5.  Oracle does not package things the same way that Debian does. The van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts and service units are quite different.  Indeed, [it even does not package things in just one way itself](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-replace-direct).

Comment: @JdeBP At the time I migrated, and mid-life Jessie, it made sense. Nowadays with the advancements in MariaDB, not so much. However it is indeed a way to have a more recent MySQL version.

Answer (score 1):

Running `sudo service mysql restart` will execute `/etc/init.d/mysql`. Consider editing that script. You'll want to pay attention to the output of:

```
$ mysqld --print-defaults
```

Comment: +1 The answer is technically correct because I forgot to mention explicitly I do not want to do that. Actually I know which associated init script I have to edit and where to change, just pooling collective knowledge if there is a cleaner way. I already have done that in my BIND and DHCP servers, and have diversions on place.